# How to update an arrays state with onChange through Child component's input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update an array which is within my Parent component's state. Each child component is created through an element from the Parent component's state array. Right now I have an onChange handler that is within my Parent component that I pass down to my Child component.

Here are some snippets that have to do with this:

Parent

```
class PropertyBar extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedCell: graph.selectedCell,
    cellProperties: []
  }

  onChangeHandler(e) {
    let cellProperties = [...this.state.cellProperties];
    cellProperties[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({cellProperties});
  }

  renderPropertyList() {
    return this.state.cellProperties.map(key => {
      return <PropertyBarItem name={key.nodeName} value={key.nodeValue} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
    })
  }
}
```

Child

```
class PropertyBarItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onChangeHandler(e) {
    if (this.props.onChangeHandler) {
      this.props.onChangeHandler(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListItem divider={true} className="property-bar-item">
        <TextField
          id="property"
          label={this.props.name}
          value={this.props.value}
          margin="dense"
          onChange={(e) => {this.onChangeHandler(e)}}
        />
      </ListItem>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't think I am handling the `onChangeHandler` passed down correctly within my Child component, but I might have the logic wrong too.

Comment: In your parent when you're passing in your handler you're passing it in as a prop of 'onChange' onChange={this.onChangeHandler} 

What happens if you try onChangeHandler={this.onChangeHandler}

Comment: @Crawdingle Ah good catch, so now it crashes after I start typing within the text field and gives me error 'Cannot read property 'cellProperties' of undefined'. Not to diverge, but is `onChange` a reserved word in react?

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, you are not using the `onChangeHandler` function correctly because you are passing it as a prop of `onChange` so it should be like this code below

```
class PropertyBarItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          input: props.value
        }
    }

    onChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({ input: event.target.value },()=>{ // callback of setState
            this.props.onChange(this.state.input) // passing the state to parent component
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListItem divider={true} className="property-bar-item">
        <TextField
          id="property"
          label={this.props.name}
          value={this.state.input}
          margin="dense"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </ListItem>
    )
  }
}
```

As well you need to bind `onChangeHandle` in your parent constructor or use arrow function like

```
  onChangeHandler = (e) => { // arrow function
     console.log(e.target.value) // check
     //let cellProperties = [...this.state.cellProperties];
     //cellProperties[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
     //this.setState({cellProperties});
  }
```

Comment: Okay it is sort of working now. The input field does not display the keys being pressed, but it shows within my console log. Also, it only logs each key that is pressed, not a concatenation of all the keys. When trying to type into a field that already has a value, it also only adds 1 key to the end of the string and console logs that.

Comment: Don't worry! I got it to work. What was wrong is that I was trying to access `cellProperties` with a `String` type instead of an `int`. Since I had converted a `NamedNodeMap` to an `Array`, I forgot that I had to access it by using an element number instead of a key. What I did was pass a counter to the `.map` function, then assigning it to the `id` property `id={this.props.id.toString()}`and using that to access the correct element within my array like `cellProperties[parseInt(e.target.id)] = e.target.value;`.

Comment: You still helped me out with my initial problem which was mapping my `onChangeHandler` correctly to my child component, so thank you for that!

Answer (score -1):

In your parent component, just  onChange replaced with  clicked = { (e) => {this.onChangeHandler(e)}  and in your chlild component us as   onChange= {this.props.clicked}

and in your parent component

```
onChangeHandler =(e)=> {
let cellProperties = [...this.state.cellProperties];
cellProperties[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
this.setState({cellProperties});}
```